# Replacing directive's element with children breaks binding in Angular - why?

Tags: angularjs, angularjs-directive

Why does replacing the directive's element with its children breaks the children's bindings?

Here's a very rudimentary example that illustrates the issue at question:

```
app.directive("foo", function(){
  return {
    template: "<input ng-model='foo'><pre>foo: {{foo}}</pre>",
    compile: function(tElem){

      // this line breaks the binding
      tElem.replaceWith(tElem.children());
    }
  };
});
```

In HTML, the usage is as follows:

```
<foo></foo>
```

Same behavior if the `replaceWith` is done in the `link` function, or if the directive's scope was set to `true` or to `{}`

[plunker](http://plnkr.co/edit/Yll2T3TCuocD6aLAdTLQ?p=preview)